# Downloading an android app directly from .apk file

Tags: android, apk

I am wondering can you create a .apk file for download without putting it on the play store? I am looking to get a couple of my friends to test an app i created but dont want to release it on the play store yet? I have tried to find different ways to do it but pretty much all of them are saying that i have to put it on the play store and then can directly download the app from a url. Thankyou for your help.

Comment: You can release it on playstore as a alpha or beta test version. Than You can invite some poeple to test your app. Only this poeple can see and download the app.

Comment: You can put the apk on your DropBox account and share its link or send the apk by eMail or put it on your IntraNet, .... If they have a file manager, they can install it (just compile it as debug), unless they enable the Unknown locations setting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Definitely yes. It can be done. Send over your APK File. When they click it, it will ask for necessary permissions and upon user clicking Accept, the app will be installed.

But, "Install from unknown sources" options should be enabled in the mobile security settings.

[image]

Comment: @RunningWalks: You can upload the APK file to your web-server. You can ask your users to just click on an URL from the mobile browser. It will download the file to the mobile phone's storage. The user can browse the mobile file system, click the file and install..

Answer (score 4):

Email the apk for instant share.

If you are planning to go alpha- and beta-testing route, it’s best to start with a small group of alpha testers (perhaps employees of your company, or a few fellow developers) and then move on to a larger group of beta testers.

In the `APK section` of your `Google Play Developer Console` you’ll find the Alpha Testing and Beta Testing tabs. Here you can upload versions of your apps’ APK files and define a list of testers as a Google Group or Google+ Community. Once this is done you’ll receive a URL that you forward to your testers, from which they can opt-in to the testing program.

[image]

After opting-in, your testers then go to your app’s product page and when they download the app Google Play will deliver them the alpha or beta version as appropriate. Incidentally, if a user happens to be opted-in to both your testing groups, Google Play will always deliver them the alpha test version.

Through alpha- and beta-testing functionality, Google Play Developer Console lets you test two different versions of your app at the same time in addition to your production version. Here’s how:

1. Select an APK for your alpha or beta test.
2. Select the group of users for each test.
3. Publish your alpha- or beta-test APK.
4. Ask your testers to opt in.

**IMPORTANT:**

- Alpha- or beta-test apps will only appear in Google Play for testers
  that opt-in and not to any other users.
- A production APK is not required to publish an alpha- or beta-test
  app.
- It may take up to 24 hours after publishing for the test link to
  become active.
- Any change you make to your app's Pricing and Distribution page
  affects Alpha, Beta, Production, and any future versions; this also
  applies to setting the price of your app (Free or Paid).

The same is mentioned at [Beta-testing and staged rollouts](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en).

If you use Android Licensing API to protect your app, then you'll need to add the beta testers emails in the list of test accounts in the `Google Play console > settings > Gmail accounts with testing access.`

Answer (score 2):

you can send the APK to them directly via email or something else and they can install it but need to have **Unknown Sources** option enabled in their devices.